# Can it be possible to write arccsc in one equation by using 2arctan?

Tags: trigonometry

I have proved the following two inverse trigonometric identities
\begin{align}
\text{arccsc}(x)&=2\arctan\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}, \qquad x\geq 1,\tag{1}\\
\text{arccsc}(x)&=2\arctan\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}, \qquad x\leq -1, \tag{2}
\end{align}
and want to write these as just one identity. But I do not like the following
\begin{gather*}
\text{arccsc}(x)=2\arctan\frac{1}{x+\text{sgn}(x)\cdot\sqrt{x^2-1}},\qquad |x|\geq 1,
\end{gather*}
where sgn denotes the singum function. Can it be possible to write  equations (1) and (2) into just one equation concerning arccsc and 2arctan, without using signum?  I have written 
\begin{gather*}
\text{arcsec}(x)=2\arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{|1+x|},\qquad x<-1 \text{ or } x\geq 1,
\end{gather*}
so I want to do so for $\text{arccot}(x).$ But I do not how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \;\text{sgn}(x) = |x|$ for real $x$, you could multiply top and bottom of the fraction by $x$ and write
$$ \text{arccsc}(x) = 2 \arctan \dfrac{x}{x^2 + |x| \sqrt{x^2-1}},\ |x| \ge 1 $$

Comment: Thank you very much. But the result you gave is more complex than the former one. Can it be  simpler?

Comment: You could try $$\text{arccsc}(x) = \arctan \dfrac{|x|}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} = \arctan \dfrac{1}{x \sqrt{1 - 1/x^2}}$$